# node server.js return nothing

Tags: node.js, terminal, nodes, node-modules

I'm very new to Node. I just installed it via Brew and when I ran `node server.js` in the Terminal, the Terminal does nothing for hours.

```
 node -v
 v6.6.0
```

This is the server file, it is from a tutorial video that I'm watching. The point of this simple express server is to allow me the ability to quickly serve test data via HTTP to the front-end.

package.json :

```
{
    "name": "simple-server",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "server.js",
    "scripts": {
         "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "start": "node server.js"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "body-parser": "^1.14.1",
        "express": "^4.13.3",
        "path": "^0.12.7"
    }
}
```

server.js file :

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

//Allow all requests from all domains & localhost
app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type,     Accept");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET");
  next();
});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/public')));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

var persons = [
    "person1.jpg",
    "person2.jpg",
    "person3.jpg",
    "person4.jpg",
    "person5.jpg",
    "person6.png"
];

app.get('/persons', function(req, res) {
    console.log("GET From SERVER");
    res.send(persons);
});

app.listen(6069);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post server.js? package.json is the package metadata file, not the server itself

Comment: @eavidan just did

Comment: Have you installed dependencies `npm install` ? Do you have something when you GET `http://127.0.0.1:6069/persons` ?

Comment: when I try installing npm it gives me 
'npm WARN simple-server@1.0.0 No repository field.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a `console.log("started!")` before `app.listen`. I'm guessing the server starts, but as is seen in your code, the only log it does is when it receives a request.

Try accessing `http://localhost:6069/persons` in your browser.

**Edit:** this defines a server response

```
app.get('/persons', function(req, res) { 
   console.log("GET From SERVER");
   res.send(persons); <-- server sends persons array to client
});
```

Comment: when I access it in my browser it gives me     ["person1.jpg","person2.jpg","person3.jpg","person4.jpg","person5.jpg","person6.png"]. I added console.log right before app.listen but nothing happened

Comment: Change console.log to console.log("started!"). Anyway, since the browser contained that array, congratulations - your server is working. However, it seems you may be lacking some knowledge, so I advise you to read a manual or in depth tutorial.